# How to make popup window topmost working?

Tags: javascript

I create waitingbox class in javascript:

```
var waitingbox = {created: false,visible: false,width: 200,height: 50,obol: null,obbx: null, obbxd: null}

waitingbox.show = function(divid,width,height){
    if (this.created){
        this.divid = divid;
        this.width=width;
        this.height=height;
        this.visible=true;
                this.topmost = false;
        this.topmost = true;
        var obbxd=this.obbxd; var obol=this.obol; var obbx =this.obbx;      obbxd.innerHTML = $(divid).innerHTML;
        obol.style.height=pageHeight()+'px';
        obol.style.width=pageWidth()+'px';
        obol.style.top=posTop()+'px';
        obol.style.left=posLeft()+'px';
        obol.style.display='block'; 
        this.center(); 
        this.togglePageElements(false);
        obbx.style.display='block';
        document.onkeydown=kd;
        
    }
}
```

How can I make this popup waitbox window on top of the window screen all the time?  I use topmost but does not work.

Comment: That is no longer supported

Comment: CSS [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) with positioning of your elements should do the trick.

Comment: I just tried this.style.zIndex = "999" but it does not work.  Any thoughts?  Thank you!